# Is it possible to have rosdep set-up a ubuntu ppa on your system as part of dependency validation?

Tags: rosdep, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to have rosdep set-up a ubuntu ppa on your system as part of dependency validation?

Of course, if you have already added the PPA to your system, you can put a dependency on that package, but is there a way for rosdep to also add that ppa to your system as well?

(On newer ubuntu versions this is done by "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name")

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9151/is-it-possible-to-have-rosdep-set-up-a-ubuntu-ppa-on-your-system-as-part-of-dependency-validation?/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As tfoote explained in https://answers.ros.org/question/70210/does-rosdep-support-installing-dependencies-from-ppas/ , this will never be possible officially and automatically (and I'm glad for it!).

The best option is to ask users of your package to add the PPA manually, and then you can even have a rosdep rule for your dependency.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is currently not possible, but it's a feature we hope to add (or would help implementing)

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2